# Programmatically deploy Safe smart contract on Polygon Mainnet

Tags: gnosis-safe, smart-contract-wallets, polygon

I have created a mobile wallet using Flutter.  I would like for users to be able to create a new Safe wallet within my app.

How can I programmatically deploy a Safe smart contract within my app?

Comment: I am still looking for a solution to deploy a Safe wallet on Polygon Mainnet.  I would like to add a feature in my wallet app for users to deploy a Safe wallet.